# Compare different Values between two columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have two columns in Excel that contain two different types of data. One has numerical data e.g. 172 and another has text data e.g. CC.
I need a formula (or even Macro) where I can look for a specific numeric value in the first column (lets call it D) and then look to the other column (lets call it G) for a specific text value and then return a result in another column (say L or such).

Example;
If value 172 is found in D, then look at G. If G contains value CC in corresponding row then return value "Contractor" in L. If not then return no value.

The result can be either a word or number, no matter. 
I have been racking my brain to try and work out a formula but get no further than an IF statement. Any advice or help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What columns? What is in D? What is in G? You must be more clear to get an answer. Perhaps a printscreen of an example.

Comment: You probably need an AND statement and a couple of MATCHs with an INDEX